Get a Razor page to pop open a new browser tab loaded with my saved URL?
I'm doing a self-tutor and have hit a wall; I've built a simple Razor web app that has 3 entities: Links, LinkTypes, and LinkAccess. Well what I'm trying to do is launch one of my Links.URL in a new browser window while (silently) logging the click to a new row in LinkAccess with the current DateTime. And I would prefer no overposting or other attacks such as Malformed URLs to enter my simple web app. Also rather not descend into the JavaScript world if possible
Since I'm old school and have too much WebForms knowledge for my own good, I've tried several approaches. None of them seems to work correctly. Response.Redirect seems to be stuck in a loop and RedirectToPage insists on confining me to the Razor-World, rather than popping a new browser tab (target=_blank) with my Links.URL in it.
Can anyone guide me to a way to accomplish this? Here's a code snippet from my CreateModel class:
public string redURL;
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync([FromRoute] int id_new)
{
// var emptyLx = new Linx();
var newLA = new LinkAccess() { LinxID = id_new, LinkAccessDateTime = DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime(), IsAdded = false };
_context.LinkAccess.Add(newLA);
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
var linxRow = _context.Linx.Where(a => a.Id == id_new).Single();
redURL = "<a href=" + linxRow.Url + " target=_blank>" + linxRow.Description + "</a>";
//return Redirect(redURL);
return RedirectToPage("/Links/Details", new {id=id_new.ToString()});
//return RedirectToPage("/LA/Redir", new {ur = redURL });
}
}


If you don't want to descend into JavaScript hell you could add the tracking to the OnGet portion of the destination page.  Not sure if you expect users to go directly to these pages or if it will only be accessed through the link, but that could be an option.

As far as I know, directly redirect to the a new page inside the razor page backend is impossible, I suggest you could modify your codes to use ajax and then use the JS window.open(response.url, '_blank'); to redirect to the new page.
More details, you could refer to below sample:
@page "/redirecttest"
@model RazorPagetest.Pages.RedirectPageModel
@{
}
<a href="#" onclick="logAndRedirect(1); return false;">Go to Link</a>

@section Scripts {
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function logAndRedirect(id_new) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '@Url.Page("/redirecttest")',
                data: { id_new: id_new },
                success: function(response) {
                    if (response.url) {
                        window.open(response.url, '_blank');
                    } else {
                        alert('Failed to retrieve the URL.');
                    }
                },
                error: function() {
                    alert('Error logging link access.');
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
}

Backend:
[IgnoreAntiforgeryToken]
public class RedirectPageModel : PageModel
{
    public void OnGet()
    {
    }


    
    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(int id_new)
    {
      
        //var newLA = new LinkAccess() { LinxID = id_new, LinkAccessDateTime = DateTime.Now, IsAdded = false };
        //_context.LinkAccess.Add(newLA);
        //await _context.SaveChangesAsync();


        //var linxRow = await _context.Linx.FindAsync(id_new);
        //if (linxRow == null)
        //{
        //    return NotFound();
        //}

        // you could generate the url byyourself
        return new JsonResult(new { url = "/index" });
    }
}

Result:


That works "tickety-boo" but I'd like to avoid the ugliness of client JS and as for CSRF and CORS, I am not concerned with that because this isn't public-facing. I had success in a slightly simpler way just by using e.g., <a href=logger.razor target=_blank> and then from that page I do the logging stuff, then call this method (I believe the Redirect Result represents the "secret sauce": public RedirectResult Index(string whither){ return Redirect(whither); }
